# JwtAuthProviderReader multiple audiences

Tags: servicestack

In looking at the JwtAuthProviderReader class I notice the audience configured in the Audience property has to exactly match the aud value in the JWT. Is there a specific reason for this? My aud value has multiple values (client is capable of accessing several discrete microservices) in it and would prefer the server side just care if the audience is contained in that list.

From Auth0 Documentation (https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-token)

> The audience. Either a single case-sensitive string or URI or an array of such values that uniquely identify the intended recipients of this JWT. For an Auth0 issued ID Token, this will be the Client ID of your Auth0 Client.

ServiceStack Source (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/JwtAuthProviderReader.cs)

```
public string GetInvalidJwtPayloadError(JsonObject jwtPayload)
    {
        if (jwtPayload == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jwtPayload));

        var expiresAt = GetUnixTime(jwtPayload, "exp");
        var secondsSinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTime();
        if (secondsSinceEpoch >= expiresAt)
            return ErrorMessages.TokenExpired;

        if (InvalidateTokensIssuedBefore != null)
        {
            var issuedAt = GetUnixTime(jwtPayload, "iat");
            if (issuedAt == null || issuedAt < InvalidateTokensIssuedBefore.Value.ToUnixTime())
                return ErrorMessages.TokenInvalidated;
        }

        if (jwtPayload.TryGetValue("aud", out var audience))
        {
            if (audience != Audience)
                return "Invalid Audience: " + audience;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity it was only supported to configure, embed and validate against a single Audience. But I've just added support for multiple Audiences in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/fd5cd7b2673f3a8d74e194dc4421b2351b24f56b).

Where you can now configure the JWT Provider with multiple Audiences, e.g:

```
new JwtAuthProvider {
    Audiences = { "foo", "bar" }
}
```

They will both be embedded in the JWT as an array, if there's only 1 audience it will continue to be embedded as a string.

When validating a JWT with multiple audiences it only needs to match a single Audience configured with the JwtAuthProvider, e.g given the above configuration:

```
JWT[aud] = null      //= Valid: No Audience specified
JWT[aud] = qux       //= NOT Valid: Wrong Audience specified
JWT[aud] = [bar,qux] //= Valid: Partial Audience match
```

This feature is available from v5.0.3 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: I don't think you intended this but the IAppSettings.GetList("jwt.Audiences"); requires that key to exist in config so it throws an exception on startup without the key in config.


I did test with an empty string for that key in the appsettings.json file and the change works as expected. Thank you!


Unrelated note I'm curious how long does it typically take to promote to official nuget feed? I hesitate to add the SS pre-release feed to our build servers package sources.

Comment: @TrentKammerer jwt.Audiences should be fixed with the latest v5.0.3 that's on MyGet. We don't have a release date for the next version which isn't in the immediate future, but the pre-release packages are exactly the same packages that would be published to NuGet which is effectively a snapshot in time release.